# How can I pass a date from my Jquery date picker to a parameter of a div element?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker, shopify

So I am trying to create a Shopify buy button that links to a product for a specific date. I need to send the selected date to the product handle, and then have the shopify button either display that product, or say the product doesn't exist. Here is what i have:

```
<html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="buttonId" data-embed_type="product" data-shop="maritix.myshopify.com" data-product_name="Ferry Riide" data-product_handle="ferry-riide" data-has_image="false" data-display_size="compact" data-redirect_to="cart" data-buy_button_text="Add to cart" data-buy_button_out_of_stock_text="Out of Stock" data-buy_button_product_unavailable_text="Unavailable" data-button_background_color="7fb466" data-button_text_color="ffffff" data-product_modal="false" data-product_title_color="000000" data-next_page_button_text="Next page">
    </div>



    <noscript><a href="https://maritix.myshopify.com/cart/17754591620:1" target="_blank">Buy Ferry Ride</a></noscript>
    <form>
        <p id="date"><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </form>
    </body>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('ShopifyEmbedScript') || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widgets.shopifyapps.com/assets/widgets/embed/client.js" id="ShopifyEmbedScript"><\/script>');
  </script>
  <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        var date = $("#date").text;
        $("#buttonId").data-product_handle = date;
        $("#buttonId").data-product_name = date;
      });
  </script>

</html>
```

Sorry if this is a mess, I am very rusty in javascript/html.

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had it

```
 $("#buttonId").data-product_handle = date;
 $("#buttonId").data-product_name = date;
```

should be

```
 $("#buttonId").data('product_handle', date);
 $("#buttonId").data('product_name' , date);
```

or

```
 $("#buttonId").attr('data-product_handle', date);
 $("#buttonId").attr('data-product_name' , date);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This helps a lot. I am now trying something a little different, so when a date is selected it adds the buy button into a div element. However, when I do this the page just keeps trying to get some sort of data from widgets.shopifyapps.com

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widgets.shopifyapps.com/assets/widgets/embed/client.js" id="ShopifyEmbedScript"><\/script>');